# heroku db:push --tables : is record id integrity maintained?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku

if in heroku i use

```
heroku db:push --tables mytable
```

is the integrity of the source table's record ids maintained?

ie if the source table has 3 records with ids 1,2 and 5 (because 3 and 4 were deleted at some stage), will those ids remain the same in heroku or will it do the equivalent of an insert and recreate the records with sequential ids (1,2,3)?

i imagine i can find this out with some trial and error, but the way we're going to build our system kind of depends on these ids remaining the same

to sum up: will all the records have the same ids after having been pushed to heroku?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It entirely replaces the tables in the target database.  For instance, if you pull an entire database, any tables which are involved in the pull no longer contain the old data.

As the data is a copy, it comes out identical to the source table.

Comment: hi neil - i know that the data is completely replaced, but will all the records still have the same ids?